# What hides nodes from roles in search results using Solr?

Tags: views, search, 9

We are hosted in pantheon and using Solr for search. At some point in the build process search stopped working for specific roles. As an admin I see all the nodes I would expect. however for some other roles, nodes dont show in search results.

If I navigate directly to that node page, I can view it with all the appropriate roles, it just does not show up in Search results.

I dont see any Search permissions that look like they would make a difference.

I can see these nodes in search results for other roles.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what would be preventing these nodes from showing in search for roles that are not restricted from viewing the nodes.

the following search modules are installed

````
        "drupal/search_api_autocomplete": "^1.7",
        "drupal/search_api_pantheon": "^8.0",
        "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.2",
        "drupal/search_api_spellcheck": "^4.0",
        "drupal/search_autocomplete": "^2.0```
````

Comment: Which Solr integration search modules are on the site?

Comment: All pages are indexed?
Have you installed any module to manage nodes permission?
In the permissions page, check if those roles are able to see the content type.
Do you have any error on your drupal log when some user/role search for a specific node that is not appearing?
On your search block, check if is everything like it should, same on the view (some filter or context filters)

Comment: "drupal/search_api": "^1.26",
        "drupal/search_api_autocomplete": "^1.7",
        "drupal/search_api_pantheon": "^8.0",
        "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.2",
        "drupal/search_api_spellcheck": "^4.0",
        "drupal/search_autocomplete": "^2.0

Comment: @pedro, Yes those pages are indexed, they appear for some roles in search but not others. We have content access installed, but even roles with permission to view at the node level do not show the node in search results

Comment: @BrandenB171 just to be sure, try to uninstall or disable the content access module, and search again, check if you have the same result or not.
Maybe the problem could be in module and not in the solr

Comment: I am curious as to why you are not using search_api_solr_devel to debug this.

Comment: @cilefen mostly because i didnt know it existed, i will install it and see what i can find

Comment: @cilefen  that module does not have a d9 version

Comment: That is untrue https://git.drupalcode.org/project/search_api_solr/-/blob/4.3.0/modules/search_api_solr_devel/search_api_solr_devel.info.yml?ref_type=tags

Comment: I found it, its just not in the module page, its bundled with search api now. Using it now thanks!

Comment: Maybe in manage processor, You enable Content access or Role-based access. There are two processor manager access by role of user.